# Why does my Tkinter window crash when I try to display a label?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, progress-bar

I am using Pycharm and Python 3.8.
My Tkinter window stops responding and causes my program to crash.
Pycharm presents the following line in its output: `Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)`
I have the following code for displaying the progress of a for loop:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import json
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.filename = ''
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Upload File', command = self.get_file).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Verify', command = self.verify).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        # tk.Label(self, text = 'some name').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.mainloop()

    def get_file(self):
        self.filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select File", filetypes = [("JSON", "*.json")])
        tk.Label(self, text = self.filename).grid(row = 0, column = 1)


    def verify():
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'Verifying Trustee Public Keys')
        lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        prog1 = ttk.Progressbar(self,
                   length = 100,
                   orient = "horizontal",
                   maximum = len(self.data["trustee_public_keys"]),
                   value = 0)
        prog1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        i = 1
        for trustee_key_list in self.data['trustee_public_keys']:
            print('Trustee :', i)
            //some code
            i = i+1
            prog1['value'] =  i
```

The get_file part works. But, when I click the `verify` button to execute the `verify() function`. The entire window freezes and I get a not responding message. 
WHat is the problem with the following part of my code?

```
lbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'Verifying Trustee Public Keys')


lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me, when I use idle, the window doesn't open. When I use sublime, the same happens.

Comment: `verify()` definition missing `self` argument.  Where is `self.data` declaration?

Comment: I am loading data from a JSON file for processing, it's basically:        
with open(self.filename) as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)